# recommended location for static & templates directories

Tags: django

I am a little bit confused about the recommended location of the templates and static directories. Apparently it is better to have 1 templates directory in every app folder. Django automatically look for templates there. However it seems not to be the case for static, is it? Can I tell django to look for static within the directory of the app currently running (instead of a single directory in the root folder)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually setting django to look where static files are.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), # basic, noqa.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "blog/other_static"), # another static folder in blog app
)
```

Django will look those folders.

and one more, you may set your static folder like `static/blog/js/some.js` and `static/otherapp/css/some_css.css`.

You may make folder in static directory named same as your app.

And I'm not suggest managing your static files in your app directory unless you're going to use your app as reusable.